# WHOIS domain name expiry date long over due

Tags: domains, whois

I just looked up this domain I was interested in obtaining but when I got the WHOIS info it showed this:

> Created On:31-Dec-2004 18:18:31 UTC
>   Last Updated On:31-Dec-2004 18:18:36 UTC
>   Expiration Date:31-Dec-2009 18:18:31 UTC
>   Sponsoring Registrar:National Informatics Centre (R12-AFIN)
>   Status:INACTIVE
>   Status:DELETE PROHIBITED
>   Status:RENEW PROHIBITED
>   Status:TRANSFER PROHIBITED
>   Status:UPDATE PROHIBITED

Now I don't have much of an understanding of how this works, but I am a bit confused. To me it looks like it expired a while ago, unless I am completely missing something here.

Comment: Even if it's expired, the registrar could be parking advertisements on it, or have it reserved for higher-level bidders because it considers the domain "premium".

Answer (score 1):

According to [PairNIC's documentation](https://www.pairnic.com/faq_basic.html), this status indicates:

> The domain name cannot expire or be deleted, regardless of the desires of the Registrant (Owner) or the registrar. If this is set, the registrar is unable to change the status.

...which doesn't sound good for you. As to why that *particular* domain is in that status, you're probably going to have to talk to the registrar in question. Since the [National Informatics Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Informatics_Centre) is a government agency of some sort, it's possible they've been granted some kind of exception to the usual processes, or there's a lock on the domain for unspecified reasons.

There's a [FAQ at indomains.net](https://www.indomains.net/faq.php), also:

> If the STATUS is PROHIBITED, that status is set by the registry and can only be removed by the registry. The registrant must contact the registrar directly to inquire about the registry-set Prohibited Statuses and to have this changed. These are the examples of a Registry status: STATUS in WHOIS DEFINITION TRANSFER PROHIBITED Registry does not allow transfer of a domain. RENEW PROHIBITED Registry does not allow renewal of a domain. DELETE PROHIBITED Registry does not allow deletion of a domain. UPDATE PROHIBITED Registry does not allow all update of a domain. Hold Registry will not allow the domain to be published to the zone.

[No permalinks, but open the "Information on .IN domains" section, then "What do the following Statuses mean in a WHOIS STATUS?" question.]